Incorrect results of GeometricSolveValues
Let us consider the following geometric problem.
A rectangle is split  into four triangles. The figure
shows the known areas of three triangles.
Find the area of the fourth (denoted by ?).

The answer is 23
and Mathematica 14.1 on Windows  finds it by
ClearAll["`*"]; GeometricSolveValues[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Line[{{c, d, e}}], 
Line[{{e, f, a}}], Area[Triangle[{b, c, d}]] == 20, 
Area[Triangle[{d, e, f}]] == 6, Area[Triangle[{a, b, f}]] == 21, 
PlanarAngle[{a, b, c}] == Pi/2, PlanarAngle[{b, c, e}] == Pi/2, 
 PlanarAngle[{c, e, a}] == Pi/2, PlanarAngle[{e, a, b}] == Pi/2}], 
 Area[Triangle[{b, d, f}]]]


{23}

It should be noted that a recrangle that satisfies the conditions
of the problem is not the only one: see the results of
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Line[{{c, d, e}}], 
Line[{{e, f, a}}],
Area[Triangle[{b, c, d}]] == 20, Area[Triangle[{d, e, f}]] == 6, 
Area[Triangle[{a, b, f}]] == 21,  PlanarAngle[{a, b, c}] == Pi/2, 
PlanarAngle[{b, c, e}] == Pi/2, PlanarAngle[{c, e, a}] == Pi/2, 
PlanarAngle[{e, a, b}] == Pi/2}], 3]

The solution becomes unique if we specify the length of some side.
In this case Mathematica can find other lengths too. For example,
GeometricSolveValues[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {Line[{{c, d, e}}], 
Line[{{e, f, a}}], Area[Triangle[{b, c, d}]] == 20, Area[Triangle[{d, e, f}]] == 6, 
Area[Triangle[{a, b, f}]] == 21, EuclideanDistance[a, b] == 4, PlanarAngle[{a, b, c}] == Pi/2, 
PlanarAngle[{b, c, e}] == Pi/2, PlanarAngle[{c, e, a}] == Pi/2, 
PlanarAngle[{e, a, b}] == Pi/2}], {EuclideanDistance[b, c],  
EuclideanDistance[b, d], EuclideanDistance[c, d], 
EuclideanDistance[a, f], Area[Triangle[{b, d, f}]]}]


{{35/2, 17 + (-1 + 4 Sqrt[5])/(5 Sqrt[6]), 16/7, 21/2, 23}}

Unfortunately, the above code with EuclideanDistance[a, b] == 40000001/10^7
instead of  EuclideanDistance[a, b] == 4 produces the same result.
This is not true as the result of
35/2*40000001/10^7 == 21+6+20+23


False

The result with EuclideanDistance[a, b] == 4000001/10^6 is
{{17 + (9 + 2 Sqrt[5])/(11 Sqrt[6]),  17 + (-1 + 4 Sqrt[5])/(5 Sqrt[6]), 16/7, 10.5, 23}} and is incorrect in view of
(17 + (9 + 2 Sqrt[5])/(11 Sqrt[6]))*4000001/10^6 == 70


False

I think Mathematica uses analytic geometry and solves numerically the certain  system
of algebraic equtions to this end. After that the RootApproximant command is applied /.x_Real :> RootApproximant[x]. Such a way was proposed by
@MichaelE2 and
@BobHanlon.
RootApproximant is not strong and this implies incorrect results. That system
in the general case  EuclideanDistance[a, b] == L is produced by
sys=GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {L}}, {Line[{{c, d, e}}], 
Line[{{e, f, a}}],  Area[Triangle[{b, c, d}]] == 20,  Area[Triangle[{d, e, f}]] == 6, 
Area[Triangle[{a, b, f}]] == 21, EuclideanDistance[a, b] == L, 
PlanarAngle[{a, b, c}] == Pi/2,    PlanarAngle[{b, c, e}] == Pi/2, PlanarAngle[{c, e, a}] == Pi/2,   
PlanarAngle[{e, a, b}] == Pi/2}, UnconstrainedParameters -> {L}]["AlgebraicFormulation"]


$ (a_1-b_1){}^2+(a_2-b_2){}^2=L^2\land (a_1-b_1)
   (c_1-b_1)+(a_2-b_2) (c_2-b_2)=0\land (d_1
   (b_2-c_2)+b_1 (c_2-d_2)+c_1
   (d_2-b_2)){}^2=1600\land (a_1-b_1)
   (a_1-e_1)+(a_2-b_2) (a_2-e_2)=0\land (a_1-e_1)
   (c_1-e_1)+(a_2-e_2) (c_2-e_2)=0\land e_2
   (a_1-f_1)+a_2 (f_1-e_1)=f_2 (a_1-e_1)\land
   (b_1-c_1) (e_1-c_1)+(b_2-c_2) (e_2-c_2)=0\land c_2
   (d_1-e_1)+e_2 (c_1-d_1)=d_2 (c_1-e_1)\land (f_1
   (a_2-b_2)+a_1 (b_2-f_2)+b_1
   (f_2-a_2)){}^2=1764\land (f_1 (d_2-e_2)+d_1
   (e_2-f_2)+e_1 (f_2-d_2)){}^2=144\land (b_2
   (c_1-d_1)+b_1 (d_2-c_2)+c_2 d_1-c_1
   d_2){}^2>0\land (a_2 (b_1-f_1)+a_1 (f_2-b_2)+b_2
   f_1-b_1 f_2){}^2>0\land (d_2 (e_1-f_1)+d_1
   (f_2-e_2)+e_2 f_1-e_1 f_2){}^2>0\land L\geq 0\land
   e_1<f_1\land a_1>f_1\land c_1>d_1\land d_1>e_1$

Here is my unsuccessful trial to solve it.
Solve[(sys /. {Indexed[a, {1}] -> a1, Indexed[a, {2}] -> a2, 
Indexed[b, {1}] -> b1, Indexed[b, {2}] -> b2, Indexed[c, {1}] -> c1, Indexed[c, {2}] -> c2,
Indexed[d, {1}] -> d1, Indexed[d, {2}] -> d2, Indexed[e, {1}] -> e1, Indexed[e, {2}] -> e2, 
Indexed[f, {1}] -> f1, Indexed[f, {2}] -> f2}, {a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2}, Reals]

It seems  the above system system is incomplete.
So the question is: is it possible to exactly and correctly  find the values
of {EuclideanDistance[b, c],  EuclideanDistance[b, d], EuclideanDistance[c, d],  EuclideanDistance[a, f], Area[Triangle[{b, d, f}]]} in the case  EuclideanDistance[a, b] == L?

Without losing of generality we can reduce list of parameters to only {c1, c2, d2, f1} (c2 or $c_2$ being OP's L).
In Solve bellow we used $c_2=7$ but can be replaced with any positive real number.
GeometricScene[{{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {0, c2}, c -> {c1, c2}, 
     d -> {c1, d2}, e -> {c1, 0}, f -> {f1, 0}}, {c1, c2, d2, 
     f1}}, {f1 < c1, d2 < c2, Area[Triangle[{b, d, c}]] == 20, 
    Area[Triangle[{f, e, d}]] == 6, Area[Triangle[{a, f, b}]] == 21}][
  "AlgebraicFormulation"];

Solve[% && Indexed[c, {2}] == 7, NonNegativeReals]

GeometricScene[{{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {0, c2}, c -> {c1, c2}, 
    d -> {c1, d2}, e -> {c1, 0}, f -> {f1, 0}}, {}} /. %[[1]], {f1 < 
   c1, d2 < c2, Area[Triangle[{b, d, c}]] == 20, 
  Area[Triangle[{f, e, d}]] == 6, Area[Triangle[{a, f, b}]] == 21}]

%["Points"]

{Area[Triangle[{b, d, c}]], Area[Triangle[{f, e, d}]], 
  Area[Triangle[{a, f, b}]], Area[Triangle[{b, f, d}]]} /. %



{20, 6, 21, 23}


+1. Thank you for your work. It does work for Indexed[c, {2}] == Indexed[c,{2}]==40000001/10000000 (To change the question is not a good style.).  However, the question is about"the case  EuclideanDistance[a, b] == L". Can you solve the general case? I will also be awaiting other responses.

@user64494 Yours L is mine $c_2$, i.e. EuclideanDistance[a, b] == L == c2. As far as I know the staff is still experimental, maybe in the future it will manage to solve also your original code.

Thank you. However, if Solve[%, NonNegativeReals] , then `%["Points"]
{Area[Triangle[{b, d, c}]], Area[Triangle[{f, e, d}]],
Area[Triangle[{a, f, b}]], Area[Triangle[{b, f, d}]]} /. %` does not work for me.

Unfortunately, GeometricSolveValues[  GeometricScene[{{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {0, L}, c -> {c1, c2},      d -> {c1, d2}, e -> {c1, 0}, f -> {f1, 0}}, {L, c1, c2, d2,      f1}}, {f1 < c1, d2 < c2, Area[Triangle[{b, d, c}]] == 20,     Area[Triangle[{f, e, d}]] == 6, Area[Triangle[{a, f, b}]] == 21}],   Area[Triangle[{b, d, f}]]] fails too.

If you want to replace c2 with L you have to did for all occurrences of c2. GeometricScene[{{a->{0,0},b->{0,L},c->{c1,L},d->{c1,d2},e->{c1,0},f->{f1,0}},{L,c1,d2,f1}},{0<f1<c1,0<d2<L,Area[Triangle[{b,d,c}]]==20,Area[Triangle[{f,e,d}]]==6,Area[Triangle[{a,f,b}]]==21}]//RandomInstance

So GeometricSolveValues[GeometricScene[{{a->{0,0},b->{0,L},c->{c1,L},d->{c1,d2},e->{c1,0},f->{f1,0}},{L,c1,d2,f1}},{0<f1<c1,0<d2<L,Area[Triangle[{b,d,c}]]==20,Area[Triangle[{f,e,d}]]==6,Area[Triangle[{a,f,b}]]==21}],Area[Triangle[{b,d,f}]]] works as expected.

Thank you. However, GeometricSolveValues[  GeometricScene[{{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {0, L}, c -> {c1, L},      d -> {c1, d2}, e -> {c1, 0}, f -> {f1, 0}}, {L, c1, d2, f1}}, {0 <      f1 < c1, 0 < d2 < L, Area[Triangle[{b, d, c}]] == 20,     Area[Triangle[{f, e, d}]] == 6,     Area[Triangle[{a, f, b}]] == 21}], {Area[Triangle[{b, d, f}]],    EuclideanDistance[a, f]}] fails.

Also fails with {EuclideanDistance[b, c], EuclideanDistance[b, d],   EuclideanDistance[c, d], EuclideanDistance[a, f],   Area[Triangle[{b, d, f}]]}.

On wolfram cloud it works.

Yes, the above code does work in Wolfram Cloud. Life consists of compromises so I accept your answer.

I appreciate:

the point of the question is illustrating issues with GeometricSolveValuesand work arounds.
The following  answer may not be appreciated. I post it for other users to illustrate Wolfram Language/Mathematica other functions can solve such problems in a timely manner and allow visualization, though not as visually pleasing as  style of GeometricScene.

Solving problem:
a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {0, y + z, 0};
c = {w + x, y + z, 0};
d = {w + x, y, 0};
e = {w + x, 0, 0};
f = {w, 0, 0};
sol = Solve[{w > 0, area > 0,
     Cross[f, b][[3]] == 42,
     Cross[e - f, d - e][[3]] == 12,
     Cross[c - d, b - d][[3]] == 40,
     Cross[d - f, b - f][[3]] == 2 ((Cross[e, b][[3]]) - 47), 
     2 area == w  y + x y + x z}, {w, x, y, z, area}, Reals] /. 
   Rule[a_, ConditionalExpression[u_, v_]] :> Rule[a, u];

Visualizing:
scene[q_] := ({a, b, c, d, e, f} /. sol[[1]])[[All, {1, 2}]] /. 
  w -> q
vis[q_] := Module[{g = scene[q], t1, t2, t3, t4},
  t1 = Triangle[{g[[1]], g[[-1]], g[[2]]}];
  t2 = Triangle[{g[[-1]], g[[-2]], g[[-3]]}];
  t3 = Triangle[{g[[-3]], g[[-4]], g[[-5]]}];
  t4 = Triangle[{g[[2]], g[[-3]], g[[-1]]}];
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Yellow], t1, Black, 
    Text[Area[t1], RegionCentroid[t1]], EdgeForm[Black], 
    FaceForm[Orange], t2, Black, Text[Area[t2], RegionCentroid[t2]],
    EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Pink], t3, Black, 
    Text[Area[t3], RegionCentroid[t3]],
    EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], t4, Black, 
    Text[Area[t4], RegionCentroid[t4]],
    MapThread[
     Text[#1, #2, {-2, -2}] &, {CharacterRange["a", "f"], g}]
    
    }, PlotRange -> Table[{0, 18}, 2]]]

Visualing an instance, vis[6] (note: all the triangle areas are calculated):

You can use Manipulate:
Manipulate[vis[p], {p, 4, 10}]


I will NOT be replying to comments

+1. Thank you for your interesting answer. All that is done rather by hand (e.g.  Cross[e - f, d - e][[3]] == 12 and  2 area == w  y + x y + x z) with help of Mathematica.
